# How to refactor this part of component more testably in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Depending on the data, the view changes. And there a common component where the internal components are inserted -DetailCmp . SomeCmp - root cmp

```
 const SomeCmp = props => (
     <div clas="random">
      ...
      <DetailCmp
          propCmp1={props.someVar === "val" ? <A {...props}/> :<B {...props}/>}
          propCmp2={props.someVar2 === "val" ? <C {...props}/> :<D {...props}/>}
          propCmp3={props.someVar3 === "val" ? <E {...props}/> :<F {...props}/>}
      />
      ...
    );
```

In DetailCmp i have

```
const DetailCmp = props => (
  <div> 
    some components ...
    ...
   {props.propCmp1}
   ...
   {props.propCmp2}
   ...
   {props.propCmp3}
  </div>
)
```

How to refactor this more declarative ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing components in `props` of `DetailCmp`, pass the props values and put all the conditions inside `DetaiCmp`.

If you pass component in `props`, unnecessary react has to maintain all the details about component in `props`, if you pass only data and put the conditions during rendering react don't have to maintain that info in props.

Like this:

```
<DetailCmp
    {...props}
/>

const DetailCmp = props => (
    <div> 
        {props.someVar === "val" ? <A {...props}/> :<B {...props}/>}
        {props.someVar2 === "val" ? <C {...props}/> :<D {...props}/>}
        {props.someVar3 === "val" ? <E {...props}/> :<F {...props}/>}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: You was first :)

Comment: Thank you, but what if there is more logic for sampling the component? It's difficult to test

Comment: didn't get you, it's almost the same way you are doing but instead of passing the component, pass the data.

Comment: There are more than 6 test cases

Comment: It's very difficult to test

Comment: @GlebPatcia by testing you mean testing of react component by enzyme or zest etc... correct? if yes then sorry don't have much idea about that.

Comment: @GlebPatcia if you are searching that solution then uncheck the answer as correct, and add a update section in your question with issue you are facing when using this approach. Some one will help you in that part :)